# npm error while creating react native app

Tags: react-native

[image]

I used following command

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app

create-react-native-app AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject
npm start
```

but it showing me following error.

anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Update your:

- Node version to the [latest](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/)
- npm (`npm install -g npm@latest`)
- yarn (`npm install --g yarn`).

And try again to run `create-react-native-app AwesomeProject`